C++ Segmentation fault occurrence with qsort -- why?
I am working through the book "Thinking like a programmer", by Anton Spraul. During exercise 3-1, I am running into some strange happenings while working with qsort.
For reference, I am using the g++ compiler (g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0) to compile this c++ code snippet.
/*
*   Exercise 3-1
*
*   Are you disappointed we didn't do more with sorting? I'm here to help.
*   To make sure you are comfortable with qsort, write code that uses the
*   function to sort an array of our student struct. First have it sort by
*   grade, and then try it again using the student ID.
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>

struct student
{
    int grade;
    int studentID;
    std::string name;
};

// forward declare compare function for qsort by grade
int compareGrades(const void* A, const void* B);

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    student studentArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {
        {87, 10001, "Fred"},
        {28, 10002, "Tom"},
        {100, 10003, "Alistair"},
        {78, 10004, "Sasha"},
        {84, 10005, "Erin"},
        {98, 10006, "Belinda"},
        {75, 10007, "Leslie"},
        {70, 10008, "Candy"},
        {81, 10009, "Aretha"},
        {68, 10010, "Veronica"}
    };

    // print unsorted array to console
    std::cout << "Initial Array\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << studentArray[i].grade << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].studentID << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].name << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    qsort(studentArray, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(student), compareGrades);

    // print sorted array to console
    std::cout << "Sorted by grade\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << studentArray[i].grade << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].studentID << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].name << '\n';
    }



    return 0;
}

// compare function for qsort by grade
int compareGrades(const void* A, const void* B)
{
    student* studentA = (student*)(A);
    student* studentB = (student*)(B);
    return (studentA->grade - studentB->grade);
}


This ends up returning a segmentation fault or a free() invalid pointer error when running this code.
I know it has something to do with qsort and strings, but oddly, when running this code, there are no errors output?
/*
*   Exercise 3-1
*
*   Are you disappointed we didn't do more with sorting? I'm here to help.
*   To make sure you are comfortable with qsort, write code that uses the
*   function to sort an array of our student struct. First have it sort by
*   grade, and then try it again using the student ID.
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>

struct student
{
    int grade;
    int studentID;
    std::string name;
};

// forward declare compare function for qsort by grade
int compareGrades(const void* A, const void* B);

// forward declare compare function for qsort by ID
int compareID(const void* A, const void* B);

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    student studentArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {
        {87, 10001, "Fred"},
        {28, 10002, "Tom"},
        {100, 10003, "Alistair"},
        {78, 10004, "Sasha"},
        {84, 10005, "Erin"},
        {98, 10006, "Belinda"},
        {75, 10007, "Leslie"},
        {70, 10008, "Candy"},
        {81, 10009, "Aretha"},
        {68, 10010, "Veronica"}
    };

    // print unsorted array to console
    std::cout << "Initial Array\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << studentArray[i].grade << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].studentID << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].name << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    qsort(studentArray, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(student), compareGrades);

    // print sorted array to console
    std::cout << "Sorted by grade\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << studentArray[i].grade << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].studentID << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].name << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    qsort(studentArray, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(student), compareID);

    // print sorted array to console
    std::cout << "Sorted by student ID\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << studentArray[i].grade << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].studentID << '\t'
                  << studentArray[i].name << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

// compare function for qsort by grade
int compareGrades(const void* A, const void* B)
{
    student* studentA = (student*)(A);
    student* studentB = (student*)(B);
    return (studentA->grade - studentB->grade);
}

// compare function for qsort by ID
int compareID(const void* A, const void* B)
{
    student* studentA = (student*)(A);
    student* studentB = (student*)(B);
    return (studentA->studentID - studentB->studentID);
}

Why would this be if qsort never interacts with the structs strings?
Thanks for anyone who can teach me a little more about pointer interactions!

Use std::sort with a suitable lambda instead.

And as a general hint: Whenever you need to use a C-style explicit conversion (a cast), you should take that as a sign that you're probably are doing something wrong.

qsort doesn't work with non-trivial types, it'll corrupt the pointers of std::string, it might work with some std::string implementations but modern implementations with small string optimisations will definitely crash

And on a different note, if you write the same code twice (or more) then you should probably create a function for that code.

That book is NOT teaching you C++ as it should currently be used. So instead of chasing ghosts from the past (void* issues) lookup std::vector and std;:sort or even better std::ranges::sort (since it allows easy sorting based on a member of the struct (projection). You might be interested in reading the C++ core guidelines so you can detect where your book is outdated

It's not so much a book on C++, but on the process of problem solving. The book was published in 2012, although this problem was slightly frustrating, I am finding the book enjoyable. Thank you to everyone who has responded!

@Mathgoy I see :) Have fun!

@Mathgoy Go here, and see the following paragraph: If the type of the elements of the array is not a PODType (until C++11) TriviallyCopyable type (since C++11), the behavior is undefined..  The probable reason for the issue is that qsort is allowed to use any means necessary to copy an object, meaning that memcpy or similar may be used to quickly swap objects -- qsort knows nothing about C++ objects, only C compatible types.  Applying memcpy on a std::string is potentially deadly.
